# Get class name while in CoroutineScope Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

javaClass.simpleName returns StanadloneCoroutinejava instead of class name name when it is called from within coroutine scope. 
I want to get the upper level class name. Any ideas how can I do so?

Comment: Could you add a small code example reproducing the situation in the question?

Comment: After the coroutine resumes, the original Java stack is gone and you can't access your caller by traversing the stack trace. I don't think there's an equivalent for coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do `this@NameOfClass::class.simpleName` you'll get the correct name.